# Using sql query Is it possible to fetch extra column which is not in table

Tags: sql, database

I have user table which has 2 fields name, city. How can i write sql query which fetch name,city,address from user table where address field is blank.
Something like this.

```
select name, city, address from user;
```

Comment: Huh? Please post example data.

Comment: Have you tried something like `select name, city, "" as address"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select any static value (including a blank), and give it an alias.

`select name, city, '' as address from user`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL

```
select name, city, 'default address' as TempField 
from user;
```

Here it would show all value for address field as "default address"